# Doctrine Orm - multiple OneToMany joins to the same table

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am struggling with the following. I am writing a basic User / Order relationship where a number of users play different roles. Each order is therefore linked to a user who is the initiator of the order, the courier (the user who is gonna pick up the order), the recipient, the user who is going to receive the order.

It stands that the Order table will have a number of relationships with the User table. Each Order will have a single user for each group, while each user can potentially have multiple relationships to the various Orders.

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error and I am not sure how to get around it:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.size AS
>   size2, t0.total AS total3, t0.initial_offer AS initial_offer4,
>   t0.user_order_owner AS user_order_owner5, t0.user_order_to AS
>   user_order_to6, t0.user_order_from AS user_order_from7,
>   t0.user_order_courier AS user_order_courier8, t0.event_collection_id
>   AS event_collection_id9, t0.event_delivery_id AS event_delivery_id10,
>   t0.currency_id AS currency_id11, t0.capacity_limitation_id AS
>   capacity_limitation_id12, t0.negotiation_id AS negotiation_id13,
>   t0.address_from_id AS address_from_id14, t0.address_to_id AS
>   address_to_id15 FROM order t0 WHERE t0.user_order_courier = ?' with
>   params [1]:

OR:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order t0 WHERE
>   t0.user_order_courier = '1'' at line 1

Each Order in the system will have a user who is a:

1. Courier
2. Recipient
3. Sender

I am bug testing with the orderCourier join and joins are as follows:

**Order Entity::**

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\User", inversedBy="orderCourier")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_order_courier", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userCourier;
```

**User Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Order", mappedBy="userCourier")
 */
private $orderCourier;
```

The full entities are as follows:

My User Entity:

```
<?php
namespace RoleBasedUser\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Rbac\Role\RoleInterface;
use ZfcRbac\Identity\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * Class User
 * @package RoleBasedUser\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="rbu_users")
 */
class User implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     *
     * @var int
     * @access protected
     */
    private $id;

    /**


* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=false, name="uuid")
     *
     * @var string
     * @access private
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=255, nullable=true, name="email")
     *
     * @var string
     * @access private
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true, name="state")
     *
     * @var integer
     * @access private
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\LocationHistory", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $location;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 */
private $lastName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 */
private $password;

//    /**
//     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Order", mappedBy="userOwner")
//     */
//    private $orderOwner;
//
//    /**                      `
//     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Order", mappedBy="userTo")
//     */
//    private $orderTo;
//
//    /**
//     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Order", mappedBy="userFrom")
//     */
//    private $orderFrom;
//
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Order", mappedBy="userCourier")
     */
    private $orderCourier;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\Feedback", mappedBy="client")
     */
    private $clientFeedback;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\Feedback", mappedBy="courier")
     */
    private $feedbackCourier;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\UserAvailability", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $pleaseUseMe;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\UserStoredLocations", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $userAddresses;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\Corporate", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="corporate_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $corporate;

    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Offer", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $offer;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="HierarchicalRole")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="rbu_users_roles",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 *
 * @var Collection
 * @access private
 */
private $roles;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 * @access protected
 */
protected $created;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 * @access protected
 */
protected $modified;

/**
 * Initiates all ArrayCollections
 *
 * @access public
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->orderOwner = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->orderTo = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->orderFrom = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->orderCourier = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->clientFeedback = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->feedbackCourier = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->pleaseUseMe = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->userAddresses = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->offer = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}

public function getRole()
{
    if(!empty($this->getRoles()[0])) {
        $roleObject = $this->getRoles()[0];
        return $roleObject->getName();
    }  else return "Not set";

}

/**
 * Set the list of roles
 * @param Collection $roles
 */
public function setRoles(Collection $roles)
{
    $this->roles->clear();
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }
}

/**
 * Add one role to roles list
 * @param \Rbac\Role\RoleInterface $role
 */
public function addRole(RoleInterface $role)
{
    $this->roles[] = $role;
}

/**
 * Add Roles to the collection
 * @param Collection $roles
 */
public function addRoles(Collection $roles)
{
    foreach($roles as $role) {
        $this->roles->add($role);
    }
}

/**
 * Remove Roles from the collection
 * @param Collection $roles
 */
public function removeRoles(Collection $roles)
{
    foreach($roles as $role) {
        $this->roles->removeElement($role);
    }
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCorporate()
{
    return $this->corporate;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $corporate
 */
public function setCorporate($corporate)
{
    $this->corporate = $corporate;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreated()
{
    return $this->created;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $created
 */
public function setCreated($created)
{
    $this->created = $created;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $firstName
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $lastName
 */
public function setLastName($lastName)
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLocation()
{
    return $this->location;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $location
 */
public function setLocation($location)
{
    $this->location = $location;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getModified()
{
    return $this->modified;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $modified
 */
public function setModified($modified)
{
    $this->modified = $modified;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $parent
 */
public function setParent($parent)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $password
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * @param string $email
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getUuid()
{
    return $this->uuid;
}

/**
 * @param string $uuid
 */
public function setUuid($uuid)
{
    $this->uuid = $uuid;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getOrderOwner()
{
    return $this->orderOwner->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderOwner
 */
public function setOrderOwner(Collection $orderOwner)
{
    $this->orderOwner->clear();
    foreach ($orderOwner as $order) {
        $this->orderOwner[] = $order;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderOwner
 */
public function addOrderOwner(Collection $orderOwner)
{
    foreach($orderOwner as $order) {
        $this->orderOwner->add($order);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderOwner
 */
public function removeOrderOwner(Collection $orderOwner)
{
    foreach($orderOwner as $order) {
        $this->orderOwner->removeElement($order);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getOrderTo()
{
    return $this->orderTo->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderTo
 */
public function setOrderTo(Collection $orderTo)
{
    $this->orderTo->clear();
    foreach ($orderTo as $order) {
        $this->orderTo[] = $order;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderTo
 */
public function addOrderTo(Collection $orderTo)
{
    foreach($orderTo as $order) {
        $this->orderTo->add($order);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderTo
 */
public function removeOrderTo(Collection $orderTo)
{
    foreach($orderTo as $order) {
        $this->orderTo->removeElement($order);
    }
}


/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getOrderFrom()
{
    return $this->orderFrom->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderFrom
 */
public function setOrderFrom(Collection $orderFrom)
{
    $this->orderFrom->clear();
    foreach ($orderFrom as $order) {
        $this->orderFrom[] = $order;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderFrom
 */
public function addOrderFrom(Collection $orderFrom)
{
    foreach($orderFrom as $order) {
        $this->orderFrom->add($order);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderFrom
 */
public function removeOrderFrom(Collection $orderFrom)
{
    foreach($orderFrom as $order) {
        $this->orderFrom->removeElement($order);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getOrderCourier()
{
    return $this->orderCourier->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderCourier
 */
public function setOrderCourier(Collection $orderCourier)
{
    $this->orderCourier->clear();
    foreach ($orderCourier as $order) {
        $this->orderCourier[] = $order;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderCourier
 */
public function addOrderCourier(Collection $orderCourier)
{
    foreach($orderCourier as $order) {
        $this->orderCourier->add($order);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $orderCourier
 */
public function removeOrderCourier(Collection $orderCourier)
{
    foreach($orderCourier as $order) {
        $this->orderCourier->removeElement($order);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getClientFeedback()
{
    return $this->clientFeedback->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param Collection $clientFeedback
 */
public function setClientFeedback(Collection $clientFeedback)
{
    $this->clientFeedback->clear();
    foreach ($clientFeedback as $feedback) {
        $this->clientFeedback[] = $feedback;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $clientFeedback
 */
public function addClientFeedback(Collection $clientFeedback)
{
    foreach($clientFeedback as $feedback) {
        $this->clientFeedback->add($feedback);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $clientFeedback
 */
public function removeClientFeedback(Collection $clientFeedback)
{
    foreach($clientFeedback as $feedback) {
        $this->clientFeedback->removeElement($feedback);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getFeedbackCourier()
{
    return $this->feedbackCourier->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param Collection $feedbackCourier
 */
public function setFeedbackCourier(Collection $feedbackCourier)
{
    $this->feedbackCourier->clear();
    foreach ($feedbackCourier as $feedback) {
        $this->feedbackCourier[] = $feedback;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $feedbackCourier
 */
public function addFeedbackCourier(Collection $feedbackCourier)
{
    foreach($feedbackCourier as $feedback) {
        $this->feedbackCourier->add($feedback);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $feedbackCourier
 */
public function removeFeedbackCourier(Collection $feedbackCourier)
{
    foreach($feedbackCourier as $feedback) {
        $this->feedbackCourier->removeElement($feedback);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getPleaseUseMe()
{
    return $this->pleaseUseMe->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param Collection $pleaseUseMe
 */
public function setPleaseUseMe(Collection $pleaseUseMe)
{
    $this->pleaseUseMe->clear();
    foreach ($pleaseUseMe as $useme) {
        $this->pleaseUseMe[] = $useme;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $pleaseUseMe
 */
public function addPleaseUseMe(Collection $pleaseUseMe)
{
    foreach($pleaseUseMe as $useme) {
        $this->pleaseUseMe->add($useme);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $pleaseUseMe
 */
public function removePleaseUseMe(Collection $pleaseUseMe)
{
    foreach($pleaseUseMe as $useme) {
        $this->pleaseUseMe->removeElement($useme);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getUserAddresses()
{
    return $this->userAddresses->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param Collection $userAddresses
 */
public function setUserAddresses(Collection $userAddresses)
{
    $this->userAddresses->clear();
    foreach ($userAddresses as $address) {
        $this->userAddresses[] = $address;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $userAddresses
 */
public function addUserAddresses(Collection $userAddresses)
{
    foreach($userAddresses as $address) {
        $this->userAddresses->add($address);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $userAddresses
 */
public function removeUserAddresses(Collection $userAddresses)
{
    foreach($userAddresses as $address) {
        $this->userAddresses->removeElement($address);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getOffer()
{
    return $this->offer->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param Collection $offer
 */
public function setOffer(Collection $offer)
{
    $this->offer->clear();
    foreach ($offer as $n) {
        $this->offer[] = $n;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $offer
 */
public function addOffer(Collection $offer)
{
    foreach($offer as $n) {
        $this->offer->add($n);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $offer
 */
public function removeOffer(Collection $offer)
{
    foreach($offer as $n) {
        $this->offer->removeElement($n);
    }
}

/**
 * @param int $state
 */
public function setState($state)
{
    $this->state = $state;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getState()
{
    return $this->state;
}

}
```

And my Order Entity:

```
 <?php
namespace Negotiation\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $size;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", length=15, nullable=true)
     */
    private $total;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     */
    private $initialOffer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\User", inversedBy="orderOwner")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_order_owner", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userOwner;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\User", inversedBy="orderTo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_order_to", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userTo;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\Feedback", mappedBy="order")
     */
    private $feedback;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\User", inversedBy="orderFrom")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_order_from", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userFrom;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoleBasedUser\Entity\User", inversedBy="orderCourier")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_order_courier", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userCourier;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Event", inversedBy="wayBillCollection")
     */
    private $eventCollection;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Event", inversedBy="wayBillDelivery")
     */
    private $eventDelivery;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Currency", inversedBy="order")
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\CapacityLimitation", inversedBy="order")
     */
    private $capacityLimitation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Negotiation", inversedBy="order")
     */
    private $negotiation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Address", inversedBy="orderFrom")
     */
    private $addressFrom;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Address", inversedBy="orderTo")
     */
    private $addressTo;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAddressFrom()
    {
        return $this->addressFrom;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $addressFrom
     */
    public function setAddressFrom($addressFrom)
    {
        $this->addressFrom = $addressFrom;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAddressTo()
    {
        return $this->addressTo;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $addressTo
     */
    public function setAddressTo($addressTo)
    {
        $this->addressTo = $addressTo;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCapacityLimitation()
    {
        return $this->capacityLimitation;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $capacityLimitation
     */
    public function setCapacityLimitation($capacityLimitation)
    {
        $this->capacityLimitation = $capacityLimitation;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $currency
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEventCollection()
    {
        return $this->eventCollection;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $eventCollection
     */
    public function setEventCollection($eventCollection)
    {
        $this->eventCollection = $eventCollection;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEventDelivery()
    {
        return $this->eventDelivery;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $eventDelivery
     */
    public function setEventDelivery($eventDelivery)
    {
        $this->eventDelivery = $eventDelivery;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFeedback()
    {
        return $this->feedback;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $feedback
     */
    public function setFeedback($feedback)
    {
        $this->feedback = $feedback;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getInitialOffer()
    {
        return $this->initialOffer;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $initialOffer
     */
    public function setInitialOffer($initialOffer)
    {
        $this->initialOffer = $initialOffer;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNegotiation()
    {
        return $this->negotiation;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $negotiation
     */
    public function setNegotiation($negotiation)
    {
        $this->negotiation = $negotiation;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $size
     */
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTotal()
    {
        return $this->total;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $total
     */
    public function setTotal($total)
    {
        $this->total = $total;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserCourier()
    {
        return $this->userCourier;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $userCourier
     */
    public function setUserCourier($userCourier)
    {
        $this->userCourier = $userCourier;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserFrom()
    {
        return $this->userFrom;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $userFrom
     */
    public function setUserFrom($userFrom)
    {
        $this->userFrom = $userFrom;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserOwner()
    {
        return $this->userOwner;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $userOwner
     */
    public function setUserOwner($userOwner)
    {
        $this->userOwner = $userOwner;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserTo()
    {
        return $this->userTo;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $userTo
     */
    public function setUserTo($userTo)
    {
        $this->userTo = $userTo;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The errors are appearing when I attempt to edit the user and the exceptions occur on: $this->updateForm->bind($object);

```
$user_id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('user_id', 0);
        $object = $this->userService->find($user_id);

        $prg = $this->prg();

        if ($prg instanceof Response) {
            return $prg;
        } elseif ($prg === false) {

            $this->updateForm->bind($object);

            return $this->getVM()->setVariables([
                    'user' => $object,
                    'form' => $this->updateForm
                ]);
        }
```

EDIT:

Essentially these three tables cause the problem, as soon as I remove them , all works as expected:

```
//    /**
//     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Order", mappedBy="userOwner")
//     */
//    private $orderOwner;

//    /**                      `
//     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Order", mappedBy="userTo")
//     */
//    private $orderTo;

//    /**
//     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Order", mappedBy="userFrom")
//     */
//    private $orderFrom;

//    /**
//     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Negotiation\Entity\Order", mappedBy="userCourier")
//     */
//    private $orderCourier;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that causes those errors?

Comment: I am opening a form to edit the user...

Comment: Thanks for your input, you put me on the right path to solve this. The problem was with the getters and setters of the entity which I discovered when I looked at what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to sort out my getters and setters. I was too focused on the annotations of the problem that I never looked towards them for a possible error.

Thanks to Svengali who got me to re-look at what I was doing wrong.

My Getters/Setters where originally like this:

```
/**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getOrderCourier()
    {
        return $this->orderCourier->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $orderCourier
     */
    public function setOrderCourier(Collection $orderCourier)
    {
        $this->orderCourier->clear();
        foreach ($orderCourier as $order) {
            $this->orderCourier[] = $order;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $orderCourier
     */
    public function addOrderCourier(Collection $orderCourier)
    {
        foreach($orderCourier as $order) {
            $this->orderCourier->add($order);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $orderCourier
     */
    public function removeOrderCourier(Collection $orderCourier)
    {
        foreach($orderCourier as $order) {
            $this->orderCourier->removeElement($order);
        }
    }
```

I changed them to:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getOrderCourier()
{
    return $this->orderCourier;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $orderCourier
 */
public function setOrderCourier($orderCourier)
{
    $this->orderCourier = $orderCourier;
}
```

And the problem no longer persists.

Thanks for the input, although it may have only been a simple question, often this is all a developer needs in order to push them in the right direction.

Comment: Do you self-writing your Setter/Getters? Doctrine can generate them for you. Also in my opinion it is not good to add custom methods to Entity because of this possible autocreation. So you simple cann remove methods and recreate them without lost functionality.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your input, I have only recently started auto creating my my mysql tables (I could not get it right due to ZF2 causing exceptions) however since moving to vagrant, these seem to have vanished. Do you have any stock standard commands you use?